# Firefox touchpad pinch to zoom not working but touch pinch to zoom works on Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, touchpad, thinkpad, touchscreen

I'm having a weird issue with Firefox on Arch Linux running on a Lenovo Thinkpad L13 Yoga. I installed Firefox, and noticed that gestures on the touchpad or the touch screen do not work. I am using gnome, and all the gnome touchpad and touchscreen gestures work properly. I then added `export MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1` to profile.d and the touchscreen gestures started working on Firefox(scrolling and zooming) but the touchpad gestures still don't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Ensure you're fully updated, BIOS and Linux. Try using [xf86-input-mtrack](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xf86-input-mtrack/) and other [advice](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Touchpad_Synaptics#Buttonless_touchpads_(aka_ClickPads)). You could also try [libinput](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Libinput), already installed in Wayland (which one are you using?).

Comment: I fully updated all packages using `pacman -Syu`. That did not seem to change anything. I also added a `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` env variable but in about:support, it still shows xwayland rather than wayland. I think the issue lies here. Libinput is already installed. I think the other two links you put seem irrelavant because they are for Xorg and not Wayland.

Comment: Perhaps [libinput-gestures](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures). The package `libinput-gestures` might exist in your repository. See [example usage](https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=8630).

Comment: From what the ArchWiki describes, it appears that libinput gestures is for gestures on Xorg apps that do not suport wayland. However, Firefox does support Wayland, but I am unable to enable it through the enviornment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out `MOZ_USE_XINPUT=1` was not alone enoguh to enable full libinput gestures, as Firefox also needed wayland to be enabled. Until now, Firefox was running through XWayland. Adding `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1` was not enough to change this, but once I added `GDK_BACKEND=wayland`, Firefox started using Wayland as the window protocol. All touch and touchpad gestures are now working.

However, the scrolling speed on the touchpad is still really fast, and I am going to try to see how I can fix that. If anyone knows how to change it, please comment it below.

Also, if anyone has an explaination for why Firefox behaves this way, and why this isn't default behaviour, please comment that down below as well.

Thank you to those who have helped.

Comment: Is this specific to Wayland and on Xorg works out of the box? I thought this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1688717 was supposed to enable pinch zoom by default for both Wayland and Xorg.

Comment: I don't know, as I have not tested on an Xorg DE. I run GNOME, which runs on Wayland + libinput by default. It might work OOTB if I used the synaptics driver with Xorg, but as the synaptics driver is no longer updated, I prefer not to use it.

Comment: I think we have our answer here: [Bug 1749174 - "Consider enabling wayland if available"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1749174).

Comment: I am on Nvidia so I can't use Wayland, only Xorg. On Xorg pinch to Zoom acts a scroll wheel. However, I've occassionally triggered some kind of inverse bug where if I do the pinch in a special way, all of them accidental, it does actually zoom in and add scrollbars instead of increasing the zoom level.

Comment: Actually, I've resolved my issue. See my answer

Comment: Nevermind, but I've gotten close: In about:config, enabling apz.gtk.touchpad_pinch.three_fingers.enabled lets you pinch with 3 fingers, but it has the wrong behavior on 2 fingers. It seems like there are 2 conflicting gestures, and the other one may be possible to also disable in about:config. I've tried browser.gesture.pinch.in and browser.gesture.pinch.out but they didn't work